# MSSQL Msg 102 '.' and column name begins with number

Tags: sql-server

I have the following issue:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near '.24'.

My SQL code is:

```
USE [DBname_Dev]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

DECLARE @ID int = 970,
        @ResourceName var char(150) = 'aa000 - TEST 2,3 & 4',
        @DevItemNum tinyint = 0,
        @Email varchar(255) = '000aa@superduper.org',
        @ItemOrg varchar(50) = '000aa',
        @ItemPOC varchar(255) = '000aa - 1234',
        @24_7POC varchar(255) = 'Test',
        @ItemDesc varchar(500) = '000aa',
        @Active bit = 1,
        @EntryArea tinyint = 1,
        @Entry int = 0
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    UPDATE
        dbo.tblItems

    SET
        ResourceName  = @ResourceName,
        DevItemNum = @DevItemNum,
        Email = @Email,
        ItemOrg = @ItemOrg,
        ItemPOC  = @ItemPOC,
        [24_7POC] = @24_7POC,
        ItemDesc = @ItemDesc,
        Active = @Active,
        EntryArea = @EntryArea,
        Entry = @Entry
    WHERE
        Id = @Id
END
```

Yes, I know it has something to do with the 24_7POC column name.  I have changed the variable declaration to @247POC, @POC24_7, as well as, @POC247.  I have the column name entered correctly with the '[24_7POC]'.  It must be something to do with the column name, but supposedly, according to Microsoft, a column starting with a number is not an issue.  I have even tried this:

```
DECLARE @POC247 as varchar(255) = 'Test' UPDATE dbo.tblItems SET [24_7POC] = @POC247 WHERE Id = 970
```

All on a single line in the SSMS 2014. This still gives me the error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near '.24'.

Even though it is on just one line.  I have searched and searched but cannot find an error with a '.' and an UPDATE statement.  I cannot change the column name, as several lines of code and stored procedures would have to be found and edited.

Any ideas?

---

Update:

I know if I try to reference the column with `tblItems."24_7"` the SSMS 2014 still shows up fine, but if I reference the column as `tblItems.24_7` it shows up with the error `Incorrect syntax near '.24'.` so that points to that exactly.  There must be a way to get the UPDATE working, in SSMS 2014 without renaming the column name.  I just haven't found it on Stack Overflow, or even Google, yet.

Comment: There is no `.24` in  your SQL and line 16 is `@ItemDesc varchar(500) = '000aa',`. Perhaps you have a poorly written `TRIGGER` on the table?

Comment: `@ResourceName var char(150)` should be `@ResourceName varchar(150)` though; which suggests that we don't actually have the real SQL here, as you would be getting the error `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near 'char'.` if you ran the above.

Comment: Line `@Email = varchar(255) = '000aa@superduper.org'` sholud be `@Email varchar(255) = '000aa@superduper.org'`, but I'm not able to reproduce the error.

Comment: Take the time to provide us with a [mre] here, as clearly the above (as you've posted it) does not replicate the problem.

Comment: Sorry about the @Email = varchar(255) = '000aa@superduper.org'.  It actually is with out the extra equls, it was a typo on my post.  I'll try the Link Larnu.

Comment: @Larnu, I gave a minimal example, with the single line.  As stated, it still gives me the same error with the same line number, even.  That doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Which is why I suggests you might have a poorly written `TRIGGER`, @MatthewMD , where `24_7POC` isn't properly delimit identified. This is just one reason why you should endeavour to avoid naming objects with names that require being delimit identified.

Comment: Maybe I didn't make it clear.  I inheritied this DB table, and several lines of code still use the column name, the way it is named.  I did not name the column, nor would I have.  It's an inherited issue.  I'm trying to find out why the other lines of code seem to work with it.

Comment: Which is why I've asked for a [mre] @MatthewMD . The SQL above does not replicate the problem, meaning we don't have the actual SQL, or the above SQL isn't the problem. The fact that it contains other syntax errors suggests the former (we don't actually have the real SQL).

Comment: Try changing the Id to something completely bogus. If this is caused by a trigger yet you don't actually update any rows then you wouldn't expect the trigger to run and thus won't see an error.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thanks.  I think you are onto something.  I tried what you said, and I get the 'Commands completed sucessfully.' message.  So what can I do about the trigger issue?

Comment: Well the error suggests dynamic sql to me. I think you'll have to take a look at the trigger code. Or perhaps there's some data in that 970 row that would point to the issue?

Comment: Well, I played with my VB code, that is accessing the DB.  After successfully editing the one row of data, straight from my stored procedure, I went about executing my VB code.  When I ran the VB code on the row, the code then seemed to corrupt that row's data, so that running just my stored procedure didn't even work on the row, after running the VB code.  I'm looking into what might be happening, but I'm not that advanced a DBA, so I haven't played with triggers yet.  Any ideas on where to look for the triggers?

Comment: I know it has something to do with the [24_7POC], as if I comment it out, it runs fine.  Is there a way to set the field name to a different name to reference the field with a different set of characers, in a SET command for UPDATE?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have found where the issue is at.  It is in a TRIGGER, for insert, update, delete:

```
DECLARE
@bit INT ,
@field INT ,
@maxfield INT ,
@char INT ,
@fieldname VARCHAR(64) ,
@TableName VARCHAR(64) ,
@PKCols VARCHAR(1000) ,
@sql VARCHAR(2000) ,
@UpdatedDate VARCHAR(21) ,
@UserName VARCHAR(64) ,
@TYPE CHAR(1) ,
@PKSelect VARCHAR(1000) ,
@OldValueSQL VARCHAR(128) ,
@NewValueSQL VARCHAR(128) ,
@fieldtype VARCHAR(32) ,
@compatible_triggerfield BIT,

select @TableName = 'tblItems'

SELECT @UserName = dbo.fnGetContextInfoString() ,@UpdateDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 114)

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
SELECT @Type = 'U'
ELSE
SELECT @Type = 'I'
ELSE
SELECT @Type = 'D'

SELECT [ID],[ResourceName],[DevItemNum],[Email],[ItemOrg],[ItemPOC],[24_7POC],[ItemDesc],[Active],[EntryArea],[Entry] INT #ins FROM inserted
SELECT [ID],[ResourceName],[DevItemNum],[Email],[ItemOrg],[ItemPOC],[24_7POC],[ItemDesc],[Active],[EntryArea],[Entry] INT #del FROM deleted

SELECT @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + 'and', 'on')
  + ' i.' + cu.COLUMN_NAME + ' = d.' + cu.COLUMN_NAME
  FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu
  WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
  AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY_KEY'
  AND     cu.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
  AND     cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

SELECT @PKSelect = COALESCE(@PKSelect+'+'.'')
  + '''<' + COLUMN_NAME
  + '=''convert(varchar(100), coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME + ',d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))+''>'''
  FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk,
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu
  WHERE pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
  AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY_KEY'
  AND     cu.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
  AND     cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
IF @PKCols IS NULL
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
  RETURN
END
IF @Type = 'I' or @ Type = 'D'
BEGIN
SET @maxfield = 1
SET @field = 0
END
```

... it has more code, but here's the kicker.  If I comment out the `SELECT @PKSELECT =`  statement, it seems to run fine.  The only other area that uses the `@PKSelect` is here:

```
SELECT @sql = '
insert Audit (    Type,
  TableName,
  PrimaryKeyField,
  FieldName,
  FieldType,
  OldValue,
  NewValue,
  UpdateDate,
  UserName)
select ''' + @Type + ''','''
+ @TableName + ''',' + @PKSelect
+ ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
+ ',''' + @fieldtype + ''''
+ @OldValueSQL
+ @NewValueSQL
+ ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
+ ',''' + @UserName + ''''
+ ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
+ PKCols
```

a bit more and then the `EXEC (@sql)` command.  I don't want to remove the `@PKSelect`, but I guess I have to, as I don't exactly understand what's going on.

Anymore help here, would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to keep it all going, without commenting out.  Take a look here:

[Trigger functions with other tables, but not this one. Msg 102](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63341202/trigger-functions-with-other-tables-but-not-this-one-msg-102/63356601#63356601)

Main difference is square braces

```
'['/']'
```

around the

```
'[' + @fieldname + ']'
```

and even the

```
'[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']'
```

I thought the braces were taken care of by the #ins and #del field selection.  Guess they aren't, but it works now.