# Trigger functions with other tables, but not this one. Msg 102

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm pulling over from a previous post of mine, [MSSQL Msg 102 '.' and column name begins with number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63192581/mssql-msg-102-and-column-name-begins-with-number/63340839#63340839).

I keep getting a Msg 102 incorrect syntax within a stored procedure, when I try to run an UPDATE.

OK, I think I have found where the issue is at.  It is in a TRIGGER, for insert, update, delete:

```
DECLARE
@bit INT ,
@field INT ,
@maxfield INT ,
@char INT ,
@fieldname VARCHAR(64) ,
@TableName VARCHAR(64) ,
@PKCols VARCHAR(1000) ,
@sql VARCHAR(2000) ,
@UpdatedDate VARCHAR(21) ,
@UserName VARCHAR(64) ,
@TYPE CHAR(1) ,
@PKSelect VARCHAR(1000) ,
@OldValueSQL VARCHAR(128) ,
@NewValueSQL VARCHAR(128) ,
@fieldtype VARCHAR(32) ,
@compatible_triggerfield BIT

select @TableName = 'tblItems'

SELECT @UserName = dbo.fnGetContextInfoString() ,@UpdateDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 114)

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
SELECT @Type = 'U'
ELSE
SELECT @Type = 'I'
ELSE
SELECT @Type = 'D'

SELECT [ID],[ResourceName],[DevItemNum],[Email],[ItemOrg],[ItemPOC],[24_7POC],[ItemDesc],[Active],[EntryArea],[Entry] INTO #ins FROM inserted
SELECT [ID],[ResourceName],[DevItemNum],[Email],[ItemOrg],[ItemPOC],[24_7POC],[ItemDesc],[Active],[EntryArea],[Entry] INTO #del FROM deleted

SELECT @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + 'and', 'on')
  + ' i.' + cu.COLUMN_NAME + ' = d.' + cu.COLUMN_NAME
  FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu
  WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
  AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY_KEY'
  AND     cu.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
  AND     cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

SELECT @PKSelect = COALESCE(@PKSelect+'+'.'')
  + '''<' + COLUMN_NAME
  + '=''convert(varchar(100), coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME + ',d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))+''>'''
  FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk,
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu
  WHERE pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
  AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY_KEY'
  AND     cu.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
  AND     cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
IF @PKCols IS NULL
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
  RETURN
END
IF @Type = 'I' or @ Type = 'D'
BEGIN
SET @maxfield = 1
SET @field = 0
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT field = 0,
  @maxfield = MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
END
WHILE @field < @maxfield
BEGIN
SELECT @field = MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
  AND ORDINAL_POSITION > @field
SELECT @bit = (@field -1)% 8 + 1
SELECT @bit = POWER(2,@bit -1)
SELECT @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1
IF SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0
  OR @Type IN ('I','D')
BEGIN
SELECT @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME, @fieldtype = DATA_TYPE
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
  AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @field
IF @fieldtype = 'text' or @fieldtype = 'ntext' or @fieldtype = 'image' SET @compatible_triggerfield = 0 else SET @compatible_triggerfield = 1
SET @OldValueSQL = ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + @fieldname + ')'
SET @NewValueSQL = ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + @fieldname + ')'
IF @compatible_triggerfield = 0
SET @OldValueSQL = ',''n/a'''
SET @NewValueSQL = ',''n/a'''
END
SELECT @sql = '
insert Audit (    Type,
  TableName,
  PrimaryKeyField,
  FieldName,
  FieldType,
  OldValue,
  NewValue,
  UpdateDate,
  UserName)
select ''' + @Type + ''','''
+ @TableName + ''',' + @PKSelect
+ ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
+ ',''' + @fieldtype + ''''
+ @OldValueSQL
+ @NewValueSQL
+ ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
+ ',''' + @UserName + ''''
+ ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
+ @PKCols
IF @compatible_fieldtrigger = 1
BEGIN
  SET @sql = @sql
  + ' where i.' + @fieldname + '<> d.' + @fieldname
  + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.'
+ @fieldname
+ ' is not null)'
  + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and d.'
+ @fieldname
+ ' is null)'
END
EXEC(@sql)
END
END
```

Here's the kicker.  If I comment out the `SELECT @PKSELECT = ...` statement, it seems to run fine.

Anymore help here, would be nice.

Comment: If the above is in a `TRIGGER` it looks like you have a design flaw. Triggers should have as minimal impact as possible. You also `SELECT` from a dataset (`inserted` and `deleted` separately) in the `TRIGGER`. A `TRIGGER` returning a dataset is deprecated and due to be removed from SQL Server; you should not do it. You also never reference those objects again, which suggests a further design flaw with the `TRIGGER`. What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve, as this seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @Larnu -- Thanks again for the response.  You are right that it was/is a Trigger issue.  As you might remember, I've inherited this code.  SO, I'm not too comfortable rewriting a Trigger.  Can I post all the Trigger somewhere, so that you could take a look at all of the Trigger code, and maybe offer some better advice?

Comment: *"Can I post all the Trigger somewhere"* Yes, in the question.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, I thought there were length limits on posts.

Comment: There is, but it's pretty long. If your trigger is too long for the question, then it's past time tog et rid of it; it'll be tanking performance.

Comment: @Larnu OK.  Here is all my Trigger code, that I have changed in the original post above.  Can you see anything that would cause the

    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
    Incorrect syntax near '.24'.

error to appear?

Comment: It appears to be missing the start. `CREATE TRIGGER...`

Comment: Also, the SQL is invalid; so it isn't complete. For example you have `@compatible_triggerfield BIT,` but then start a `SELECT` afterwards. Either finish the `DECLARE` or continue it. You also mistype `INTO` as `INT`. That is ***not*** your Trigger... Like I said last time, actually give us the code. If that is your trigger, is doesn't work, and will cause errors every time some operation (what ever it is) occurs.

Comment: It's from an ALTER TRIGGER statement, so I left that out.  We only need to know the actual procedure calls to get it functioning properly.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, if I have typos.  I cannot copy it exactly from my code.  I have to type while looking at another screen.  I'll correct them.  Sorry.

Comment: Unless you can give a statement that actually parses, we can't help you , Matthew, as we'll *assume* the reason your code isn't working is because of said typographical errors. Take the time to check your code parses, and then post it. Even if I fix those 3 errors, there's still more, and I am not entertaining fixing typographical errors to then find the real problem.

Comment: @Larnu - Thanks for not being pretentious.  NOte.  If it parsed I wouldn;t be posting now would I?

Comment: The trigger wouldn't exist if it didn't parse, Matthew. But if you're therefore trying to create said trigger, then stop, and don't. That should ***not*** be a `TRIGGER`. As I have said repeatedly, and why I've asked for the *real* problem.

Comment: Also, it's long past time to stop using those old ANSI-89 JOINs. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @Larnu The REAL PROBLEM is posted above.  The Trigger returns a Msg 102 when the `SELECT @PKSelect` is used.

Comment: No, the *real* problem is something else. That `TRIGGER` should not exist. Like I have said before, a `TRIGGER` should be minimal, and the above is *far* from that. Which is why we need to understand what you are trying to achieve with that trigger. The fact that it;s running (unsanitised) dynamic SQL is both a concern and even bigger indicator that it should not be a trigger.

Comment: @Larnu Again, I inherited this code.  It is being used to track changes in the DB table tblItems of the fields listed.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I don't know, I don't know what the *real* goal is.

Comment: If this is a bad `TRIGGER` then the _goal_ is to find a `TRIGGER` that can record changes to fields in the database table, or fix this one so that it can do that.

Comment: Why not implement [change tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)?If not, that doesn't answer why there's dynamic SQL. It should simply be inserting the "old" row elsewhere to retain a copy in an archive table.

Comment: @Larnu  That does look very nice, but we are stuck on SQL Server 2014 for right now.  Change Tracking does not seem to be available to servers prior to 2016.  I do admit, that would be nice, to use Change Tracking, and I appreciate your suggestion, but it is unavailable on the server(s) we have now.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.  I added a few more '['/']' (square brackets) in the code.  All this, without help from @Larnu, who is somewhat an Arse.  Larnu always wants to point out what is wrong, and not offer what could be right.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tblItems_ChangeTracking] on [dbo].[tblItems] for insert, update, delete
AS
DECLARE @bit INT ,
@field INT ,
@maxfield INT ,
@char INT ,
@fieldname VARCHAR(64) ,
@TableName VARCHAR(64) ,
@PKCols VARCHAR(1000) ,
@sql VARCHAR(2000) ,
@UpdatedDate VARCHAR(21) ,
@UserName VARCHAR(64) ,
@TYPE CHAR(1) ,
@PKSelect VARCHAR(1000) ,
@OldValueSQL VARCHAR(128) ,
@NewValueSQL VARCHAR(128) ,
@fieldtype VARCHAR(32) ,
@compatible_triggerfield BIT

select @TableName = 'tblItems'

SELECT @UserName = dbo.fnGetContextInfoString() ,@UpdateDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 114)

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
SELECT @Type = 'U'
ELSE
SELECT @Type = 'I'
ELSE
SELECT @Type = 'D'

SELECT [ID],[ResourceName],[DevItemNum],[Email],[ItemOrg],[ItemPOC],[24_7POC],[ItemDesc],[Active],[EntryArea],[Entry] INTO #ins FROM inserted
SELECT [ID],[ResourceName],[DevItemNum],[Email],[ItemOrg],[ItemPOC],[24_7POC],[ItemDesc],[Active],[EntryArea],[Entry] INTO #del FROM deleted

SELECT @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + 'and', 'on')
  + ' i.[' + cu.COLUMN_NAME + '] = d.[' + cu.COLUMN_NAME + ']'
  FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
 INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu
  WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
  AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY_KEY'
  AND     cu.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
  AND     cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

SELECT @PKSelect = COALESCE(@PKSelect+'+'.'')
  + '''<' + COLUMN_NAME
  + '=''convert(varchar(100), coalesce(i.[' + COLUMN_NAME + '],d.[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']))+''>'''
  FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk,
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE cu
  WHERE pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
  AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY_KEY'
  AND     cu.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
  AND     cu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
IF @PKCols IS NULL
BEGIN
  RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
  RETURN
END
IF @Type = 'I' or @ Type = 'D'
BEGIN
SET @maxfield = 1
SET @field = 0
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT field = 0,
  @maxfield = MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
END
WHILE @field < @maxfield
BEGIN
SELECT @field = MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
  AND ORDINAL_POSITION > @field
SELECT @bit = (@field -1)% 8 + 1
SELECT @bit = POWER(2,@bit -1)
SELECT @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1
IF SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0
  OR @Type IN ('I','D')
BEGIN
SELECT @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME, @fieldtype = DATA_TYPE
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName
  AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @field
IF @fieldtype = 'text' or @fieldtype = 'ntext' or @fieldtype = 'image' SET @compatible_triggerfield = 0 else SET @compatible_triggerfield = 1
SET @OldValueSQL = ',convert(varchar(1000),d.[' + @fieldname + '])'
SET @NewValueSQL = ',convert(varchar(1000),i.[' + @fieldname + '])'
IF @compatible_triggerfield = 0
SET @OldValueSQL = ',''n/a'''
SET @NewValueSQL = ',''n/a'''
END
SELECT @sql = '
insert Audit (    Type,
  TableName,
  PrimaryKeyField,
  FieldName,
  FieldType,
  OldValue,
  NewValue,
  UpdateDate,
  UserName)
select ''' + @Type + ''','''
+ @TableName + ''',' + @PKSelect
+ ',''[' + @fieldname + ']'''
+ ',''' + @fieldtype + ''''
+ @OldValueSQL
+ @NewValueSQL
+ ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
+ ',''' + @UserName + ''''
+ ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
+ @PKCols
IF @compatible_fieldtrigger = 1
BEGIN
  SET @sql = @sql
  + ' where i.[' + @fieldname + '] <> d.[' + @fieldname
  + '] or (i.[' + @fieldname + '] is null and  d.['
+ @fieldname
+ '] is not null)'
  + ' or (i.[' + @fieldname + '] is not null and d.['
+ @fieldname
+ '] is null)'
END
EXEC(@sql)
END
END
```

I did have help from a coworker, and this appears to work.

It seems to work, without needing the entry of '[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']', but better safe than sorry.